# ASP.NET MVC with WEB.API and Castle Windsor container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET MVC application with integrated Castle Windsor container. When I added ApiController, and tried to do POST, I got an error message: "Make Sure That the controller has a parameterless public constructor."  Thanks for any advice.

Castle Windsor integration:

```
public class CastleControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public IWindsorContainer Container { get; protected set; }

    public CastleControllerFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("container");
        }

        this.Container = container;
    }        

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;

    }               

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        var disposableController = controller as IDisposable;
        if (disposableController != null)
        {
            disposableController.Dispose();
        }

        Container.Release(controller);
    }
}

public class DefaultCastleInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        //Functions
        //container.Register(Component.For<IGetIPAddressesFromRange>().ImplementedBy<GetIPAddressesFromRange>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>().LifestylePerWebRequest());

        var contollers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(Controller)).ToList();
        foreach (var controller in contollers)
        {
            container.Register(Component.For(controller).LifestyleTransient());
        }

        var apiContollers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(ApiController)).ToList();
        foreach (var apiController in apiContollers)
        {
            container.Register(Component.For(apiController).LifestyleTransient());
        }
    }
}

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        //Integrace CastleWindsor
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(new DefaultCastleInstaller());
        var castleControllerFactory = new CastleControllerFactory(container);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(castleControllerFactory);
    }
}
```

ApiController:

```
 public class UserVerificationController : ApiController
 {
   private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

   /// <summary>
   /// Konstruktor
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="unitOfWork"></param>
   public UserVerificationController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
   {
       _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
   }

   // GET api/<controller>
   public IEnumerable<string> Get()
   {
       return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that because MVC and Web API controllers are separate entities, you need Windsor configuration for both. You've got Windsor configured to create your MVC controllers. You just need the same for your Web API controllers.

Here's a Web API controller activator, mostly lifted from [this blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/).

```
public class WindsorWebApiControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorWebApiControllerActivator(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
        Type controllerType)
    {
        var controller =
            (IHttpController)this._container.Resolve(controllerType);

        request.RegisterForDispose(
            new Release(
                () => this._container.Release(controller)));

        return controller;
    }

    private class Release : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Action _release;

        public Release(Action release)
        {
            _release = release;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _release();
        }
    }
}
```

And you need to register all of the controller types with the container. Here's an `IWindsorInstaller` that registers all MVC *and* Web API controllers:

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Classes.
                FromThisAssembly().
                BasedOn<IController>(). //MVC
                If(c => c.Name.EndsWith("Controller")).
                LifestyleTransient());

        container.Register(
            Classes.
                FromThisAssembly().
                BasedOn<IHttpController>(). //Web API
                If(c => c.Name.EndsWith("Controller")).
                LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

Then at startup replace the default Web API controller activator with yours:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(
    typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
    new WindsorWebApiControllerActivator(container));
```

and be sure to call the installer:

```
container.Install(new ControllersInstaller());
```